# dependency (for javax.script) of SBT build

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I am using [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/index.html) to build my scala project. I have also java code in my project.

When I run the build I constantly get the following error:

```
package javax.script does not exist
[error] import javax.script.Invocable;
```

I understand that I need to declare dependency to the javax.script.* , but I don't what is the dependency I should depend on?

My **build.sbt** contains:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "org.springframework" % "spring-dao" % "2.0.8",
)
```

What is the name of dependency I should add ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `javax.script` is part of Java since Java 6. But perhaps try this:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.sun.phobos" % "jsr223-api" % "1.0"
```